# Não consigo Inserir dados números float

Tags: php, mysqli, crud

```
<?php 
    require_once('cabecalho.php'); 
    require_once('conn.php'); 
?>
<?php
    $nome = $_REQUEST["nome"];
    $preco = $_REQUEST["preco"];              
    $query = "insert into produtos (nome, preco) values ('{$nome}', '{$preco}')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){ ?>
    <p class="alert-success">Produto <?= $nome ?> <?= $preco ?> adicionado.</p>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <p class="alert-danger">Produto <?= $nome; ?> não foi adicionado.</p>    
    <?php } ?>   
        </header>
    </section>
<?php include('rodape.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Tenta utilizar a [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.error.php) para exibir uma mensagem de erro que seja útil para você em desenvolvimento.

Comment: *"Não consigo inserir no banco de dados"* é meio vago/genérico, já que isso pode ter **muitas** causas diferentes. Pode ser os valores são de um tipo diferente do que está definido no banco, ou fora dos valores permitidos (ultrapassou tamanho máximo, é `null` quando a coluna não permite, etc etc etc), ou qualquer outra coisa. Por favor clique no link [edit] logo abaixo das tags da pergunta e adicione mais informações (estrutura da tabela, dados a serem inseridos, mensagem de erro, etc), pois do jeito que está, não temos como adivinhar. Tente fazer com que a pergunta contenha um **[mcve]**

Answer (score 1):

Talvez o problema esteja na conexão ou no comando SQL, tente fazer o comando SQL dessa forma pra ver se funciona:

```
$query ="INSERT INTO prudutos (nome,preco)VALUES ('$nome','$preco')";
```

Comment: Quando o número é inteiro dá certo. Já quando o é float dá erro. Na tabela esta definida decimal(10,2)

Comment: Na realidade o problema é a virgula. O que posso fazer ?

Comment: Vi que estava fazendo muitas coisas erradas. No caso meu primeiro erro, foi não definir o input do preço com 'number'. E após definir como 'number' descobri o atributo step do html 5. defini como 'step='0.01' e deu certo.